# group by con máxima fecha y ultimo precio de costo

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito obtener el precio de costo de el registro con fecha mayor, para ello uso las siguientes tablas:

Tabla **ingreso_mercancias_cabecera**

```
select * from ingresos_mercancias_cabecera
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla **ingresos_mercancias_detalle**

```
select * from ingresos_mercancias_detalle
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla **productos**

```
select * from productos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero obtener es una tabla donde se obtenga el *codigo_barras*, *precio_entrada* y *fecha*

para eso estoy usando esta consulta:

```
select p.codigo_barras, 
            i.precio_entrada, 
            max(ic.fecha) as fecha
from ingresos_mercancias_detalle i, 
ingresos_mercancias_cabecera ic, productos p  
where i.id_ingreso_cabecera=ic.id 
and i.id_producto=p.id 
group by i.precio_entrada, p.codigo_barras, p.id
order by p.id
```

pero me da como resultado esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NO** quiero que los resaltados en rojo me aparezcan en la consulta.

Gracias.

Query para creacion de DB.

```
CREATE TABLE familias
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nombre character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT pkfamilias PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE marcas
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nombre character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT pkmarcas PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE productos
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_marca integer NOT NULL,
  id_familia integer NOT NULL,
  codigo_barras character varying,
  descripcion character varying(500),
  precio_costo double precision,
  precio_venta double precision,
  precio_mayorista double precision,
  precio_credito double precision,
  cant_paquete integer,
  iva integer,
  CONSTRAINT clave_primaria PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_familia FOREIGN KEY (id_familia)
      REFERENCES familias (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_marca FOREIGN KEY (id_marca)
      REFERENCES marcas (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT productos_codigo_barras_key UNIQUE (codigo_barras)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


CREATE TABLE ingresos_mercancias_cabecera
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  no_factura character varying(100),
  id_proveedor integer,
  total double precision,
  fecha date,
  hora character varying(8),
  CONSTRAINT pk_ingresos PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE ingresos_mercancias_detalle
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_producto integer,
  id_ingreso_cabecera integer,
  cantidad double precision,
  precio_iva double precision,
  precio_entrada double precision,
  CONSTRAINT pk_ingresos_detalle PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_cabecera FOREIGN KEY (id_ingreso_cabecera)
      REFERENCES ingresos_mercancias_cabecera (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_producto FOREIGN KEY (id_producto)
      REFERENCES productos (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que te está faltando es determinar cuales son las fechas máximas para cada producto en la tabla de detalle y filtrar la consulta con esas fechas.

El query quedaría así:

```
select p.codigo_barras, 
       i.precio_entrada, 
       maximos.fecha
from ingresos_mercancias_detalle i, 
ingresos_mercancias_cabecera ic, 
productos p, 
(   select p.id, max(ic.fecha) as fecha
    from ingresos_mercancias_detalle i, 
    ingresos_mercancias_cabecera ic, 
    productos p  
    where i.id_ingreso_cabecera=ic.id 
    and i.id_producto=p.id 
    group by p.id
) maximos 
where i.id_ingreso_cabecera=ic.id 
and i.id_producto=p.id 
and i.id_producto = maximos.id 
and ic.fecha = maximos.fecha   
order by i.id_producto;
```

Comment: ya voy a agregar los create table a la pregunta original

Comment: Corrí el query y corregí una condición que estaba mal seteada. Ahora funciona. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdXe9syNGnWnT386ePdtit/2